# how whould I parse JSON with numerical object keys in Jackson JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I just started using Jackson JSON parser, and I love it, but I've run into a problem with a JSON object I'm trying to parse.

here's my current java code:

```
public class resetPassword {
    private String id;
    private String key1;
    private String key2;


    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id= id;
    }

    public String getKey1() {
        return key1;
    }

    public void setKey1(String key1) {
        this.key1= key1;
    }

    public String getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }

    public void setKey2(String key2) {
        this.key2= key2;
    }
}
```

how would I parse something like this in Jackson:

```
{
   "1":{
      "key1":"val",
      "key2":"val"
   },
   "2":{
     "key":"val",
     "key":"val"
     }, .. etc
}
```

any help with this would be greatly apreceated

Comment: what the actual problem?

Comment: I keep getting an error saying that it cannot map that json to that object. I will try to track down the exact error it's outputing.

Comment: The Json format is fixed or can you change it? I think a better fit to the domain may be to turn the outer object into an array. This would also eliminate mapping difficulties.

Comment: In the JSON you have object with keys `1` and `2` (etc.). So you probably need Java object with attributes that correspond to these keys. I think it will be a little problem to create a Java class with atributes with numerical names...

Comment: well... it's sort of fixed... I would prefer to change it, but there are other systems that rely on that data being in it's current format.

Comment: is there a way to maybe manually map just the numeric keys and let the system map the other values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information in comments, I guess you need to combine traversing with data binding.

First, using [traversal](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-json-tree-parsing.jsp), get `JsonNode` objects with `{"key1": ..., "key2": ...}`. 
Pseudocode (not tested):

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(genreJson);
    Iterator<String> fieldNames = root.fieldNames();
    while (fieldNames.hasNext()) {
        String fieldName = fieldNames.next();
        JsonNode node = root.get(fieldName);
        // now you should have {"key1": ...} in node
    }
```

Then use [data binding](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-Data-Binding.jsp) for each node you found:

```
ResetPassword item = mapper.readValue(node, ResetPassword.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a quick way, you can set it to a `Map`;

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = mapper.readValue(br, Map.class);
System.out.println(map);
```

Your `map` would now be:

```
{1={key1=val, key2=val}, 2={key1=val, key2=val}}
```

You can iterate over the `Map(s)` and set your `ResetPassword` accordingly.

PS: *br* is my `BufferedReader` instance which reads the `json` placed in `numeric.txt`,

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("numeric.txt"),    "UTF-8"));
```